# How to get AccessToken from RefreshToken in GoogleAuthUtil

Tags: google-authentication

I have a problem with GoogleAuthUtil . 
In first getToken i receive a AccessToken
and when AccessToken has expired time , getToken recive a RefreshToken .

How get a AccessToken from RefrestToken ?

Thaks so much

Answer (score 0):

Basically, GoogleAuthUtil is used for getting an access token for an account which is on a device. So there's no way for GoogleAuthUtil to exchange for an access token given a refresh token.